# Move closing </a> tag

Tags: jquery

I have a pdf link with the filesize as follows...

```
<a class="pdf-link" href="some-pdf.pdf">Some PDF</a> <span class="filesize">(PDF 100kb)</span>
```

The link is generated by our CMS and for our mobile site the span needs to sit within the link.

Would anyone know of a way to move the closing `</a>` tag to the end of the span, preferably with jQuery?

```
<a class="pdf-link" href="some-pdf.pdf">Some PDF <span class="filesize">(PDF 100kb)</span></a>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.filesize').each(function() {
   $(this).appendTo($(this).prev());
});
```

You don't need to manually remove the content, as `appendTo` moves your DOM internally, from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

> We can also select an element on the page and insert it into another:
>
> $('h2').appendTo($('.container'));
>
> If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be
>   moved into the target (not cloned):

Comment: I think you need to remove the original as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(".filesize").each( function(index) {
    $(this).prev().append(this);
});​
```

See the demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hammerbrostime/u9r2z/